# Web Socket Digital Signature

Tags: digital-signature

I recently downloaded the websocket digital signature by Damain Falconi from GitHub https://github.com/damianofalcioni/Websocket-Smart-Card-Signer , When i tried installed the token `dll` that are inside the software it gives me error.

I've tried adding `jna 4.3.0` jar files but still it gives me error. Please help

```
 C.NATIVE = new JNA(library);
```

This gives me error

Should be loaded successfully

Comment: What error do you get? Error messages aren’t there just for fun, they explain what is wrong. Always include them in the question.

Comment: The constructor JNA(String) is undefined

Comment: Using browser extension is one option here... [Signer.Digital](https://signer.digital/SignerDigitalBrowserExtensions) is one such free extension provided by my company.  This just uses installed USB or smartcard driver and underlaying CSP to read Certificate Store and sign from Browser.